# Executable on host request vb6

Tags: http, request, vb6, hosting, executable

first I am not sure even if this will be possible, but I'll try to explain, and I'll wait for answers.

I have a small project which works with executable files, here is the example, it's not the full code, just some part of the code, so:

```
Dim x()  As Byte

Open App.Path & "\Myfile.exe" For Binary As #1
ReDim x(0 To LOF(1) - 1)
Get #1, , x
Close #1
```

Here is my code, as you can see everything seems fine because  "Myfile.exe" is in on my local pc, the problem is, i can use that method only on my local pc, for example, if "Myfile.exe" is in another pc, the program won't work since, "Myfile.exe" is not on the pc and cannot be detected.

So my  idea is, if i upload "Myfile.exe" on  host,  to set the path to that host with request, would it work?

I saw method with

`MSXML2.XMLHTTP` and `srvXmlHttp.Open "GET", "MyexampleHost", False srvXmlHttp.send`

Something important, I don't need the file which will be uploaded on the host to be downloaded, it just needs to  find the path to the host and verify the file is there. If anyone is wondering why I don't just use both files in the same place, it's just that the example file should be hidden.

As i say i tried some ways with

```
"MSXML2.XMLHTTP" and srvXmlHttp.Open "GET", "MyexampleHost", False

srvXmlHttp.send
```

Comment: Are you asking how to download a file over HTTP or HTTPS?  Unless your file is in a location which can accesses like a normal filessytem path (which a web server normally cannot be) then you will have to copy it locally first, and only then can you read its bytes using the method shown in this question. But the question doesn't seem to be 100% clear.